# drupal views : display previous nodes

Tags: views

I am having difficulties to filter data with views. I have made several video lessons on a subject and managed to display on the side of each video all other related videos in a block. 
However i wish to see displayed in this block all related AND Previous videos.

I created a field called "order" (integer) in my content type, and i wonder how i can add a filter to make sure that the related videos have an "order" value lower than the "order" value of the video being displayed.

I 'd be greateful if anybody could help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to create a page/block (basically just a different views display) to achieve that.

The constraints that you have i.e. Previous and Related can only find a practical application if your videos belong to the same category.

If I am getting the question right what you are better off doing is creating another block which displays all videos irrespective of the categories.